# Show/hide DIV's by many different selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am try to hide and show different DIV's by based on two different selects values. I want to make search in real estate catalog by season and term of rent. This is the selects:

```
<select id="test" name="form_select" onchange="showDiv(this)">
       <option value ="hui">Choose term</option>
       <option value="0">Month</option>
       <option value ="1">Week</option>
       <option value ="2">Day</option>
    </select>
   <select id="test" name="form_select" onchange="showDiv1(this)">
       <option value ="hui">Choose season</option>
       <option value="0">Low</option>
       <option value ="1">Hight</option>
       <option value ="2">Peak</option>
    </select>
```

I used the script:

```
 function showDiv(elem){if(elem.value == 0)
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_lowmonth').style.display = "block";
  else
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_lowmonth').style.display = "none";if(elem.value == 1)
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_lowweek').style.display = "block";
  else
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_lowweek').style.display = "none";if(elem.value == 2)
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_lowday').style.display = "block";
  else
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_lowday').style.display = "none";if(elem.value == 0)
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_hightmonth').style.display = "block";
  else
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_hightmonth').style.display = "none";if(elem.value == 1)
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_hightweek').style.display = "block";
  else
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_hightweek').style.display = "none";if(elem.value == 2)
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_hightday').style.display = "block";
  else
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_hightday').style.display = "none";if(elem.value == 0)
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_peakmonth').style.display = "block";
  else
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_peakmonth').style.display = "none";if(elem.value == 1)
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_peakweek').style.display = "block";
  else
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_peakweek').style.display = "none";if(elem.value == 2)
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_peakday').style.display = "block";
  else
  document.getElementById('tr_ad_peakday').style.display = "none";if(elem.value == 0)
  document.getElementById('searchfields').style.display = "block";if(elem.value == 1)
  document.getElementById('searchfields').style.display = "block";if(elem.value == 2)
  document.getElementById('searchfields').style.display = "block";
    }
```

Here is my div:

```
<div id="searchfields" style="display:none;">
        <?php 
        foreach($this->searchfields as $fsearch) {
            $title = $this->field->showFieldTitle($this->catid,$fsearch);
            echo "<div id='tr_".$fsearch->name."'>".htmlspecialchars($title)."";
            $this->field->showFieldSearch($fsearch,$this->catid,null);
            echo "</div>";
        }?> 
       </div>
```

I whant to do when i choose the low season and week , it shows me only DIV with ID "tr_ad_lowweek" .

Comment: Firstly, you should avoid using the same id for both the select tags

Comment: Not exactly related, but wouldn't it be simpler to put the `id`s to `value`s of `option`s instead of a huge block of `if..else`?

Comment: Why not group your `if`s, makes for better maintainability and easier reading

Comment: Why not just remove the if's and join the values from the selects to a selector, then write a filter and this could be done in a few lines of code instead of this mess ?

Comment: something more like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Lex6K/**

Comment: Please, can you give fulle xample with DIV's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [my](http://jsfiddle.net/JeekOnline/Lex6K/8/) fiddle : Where you are able to get/Generate DIV selector. Then you can use this as selector and render the corresponding selector contents.

//JS : Select.js

```
$('#term, #season').on('change', function() {
 $('div[id^="ad_"]:gt(3)').css("display","none");

      var term   = $.trim( $('#term :selected').text().toLowerCase() ),
      season = $.trim( $('#season :selected').text().toLowerCase() );
 if($('#term :selected').val() > 0 && $('#season :selected').val() > 0)   {
          var $sel = '#ad_' + season + term;
          $($sel).css("display","block");

   }
```

});

//HTML

```
<select id="term" name="form_select">
  <option value="0">Choose term</option>
  <option value="1">Month</option>
  <option value="2">Week</option>
  <option value="3">Day</option>
</select>
<select id="season" name="form_select">
  <option value="0">Choose season</option>
  <option value="1">Low</option>
  <option value="2">Hight</option>
  <option value="3">Peak</option>
</select>

<div id="tr_ad_lowmonth">tr_ad_lowmonth</div>
<div id="tr_ad_lowweek">tr_ad_lowweek</div>
<div id="tr_ad_lowday">tr_ad_lowday</div>
<div id="tr_ad_hightmonth">tr_ad_hightmonth</div>
<div id="tr_ad_hightweek">tr_ad_hightweek</div>
<div id="tr_ad_hightday">tr_ad_hightday</div>
<div id="tr_ad_peakmonth">tr_ad_peakmonth</div>
<div id="tr_ad_peakweek">tr_ad_peakweek</div>
<div id="tr_ad_peakday">tr_ad_peakday</div>
```

//CSS

```
 div{
   display:none;    
  }
```

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/Lex6K/5/ i add DIV's , and i think it doesn't works.

Comment: It works perfect in Fiddle, but don't want to work on my site... Maybe you know why? Script loads in select.js wit no errors, div's load, css works but it dont work :) here -  http://sales.aboutphuket.ru/index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=search&catid=10&Itemid=1398

Comment: I am not able to find div selector for ex: #tr_ad_lowweek ? can you please locate?

Comment: Please, try to find <div id='tr_ad_lowweek'> in CTR+U mode. It is after selects. It generates by this php - <?php 
   foreach($this->searchfields as $fsearch) {
    $title = $this->field->showFieldTitle($this->catid,$fsearch);
    echo "<div id='tr_".$fsearch->name."'>".htmlspecialchars($title)."";
    $this->field->showFieldSearch($fsearch,$this->catid,null);
    echo "</div>";
   }?>

Comment: And i removed tr_ preffix , now it is ad_lowweek

Comment: I think problem in Jquery, because i got error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQ is not defined jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js:5
(anonymous function)

Comment: Yes, try by replacing jQ with $ . For more refer this : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: This is the second problem , But don't forget to include my changes in your select.js file. OK

Comment: Ok, thank you , i realy grateful for help! Do you make changes in jsfiddle.net/JeekOnline/Lex6K/8 ?

Comment: I have updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JeekOnline/Lex6K/11/ as per your requirement. please check.

Comment: I tried to run it all the day but it don't wants work. I removed all the libraries except Jquery libs from google: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> but it don't work, i got an error - $('#term, #season').on('change', function() {
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Ok, it solved, it was because select.js loaded before JQuery libs, it is my fault. Now page loads with no errors, but select don't work :)

Comment: Ok, problem was in JS, please correct JS block on:$(function () {
     $('#term, #season').on('change', function () {
         $('div[id^="ad_"]:gt(3)').css("display", "none");

         var term = $.trim($('#term :selected').text().toLowerCase()),
             season = $.trim($('#season :selected').text().toLowerCase());
         if ($('#term :selected').val() > 0 && $('#season :selected').val() > 0) {
             var $sel = '#ad_' + season + term;
             $($sel).css("display", "block");

         }

     });
 });                     I changed it in Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lex6K/15/